# Is there a solution to these matrix equations?

Tags: matrix-equations

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices such that:

$$A\neq 0$$
$$B \neq 0$$
$$A^2=0$$
$$B^2=0$$
$$AB=A$$
$$BA=B$$

Is there a solution to this set of equations? I tried looking for a solution in $2\times 2$ matrices but couldn't find one. Is there a way to prove no such solution exists for $n \times n$ matrices?

(Or if it makes a difference the last two can be replaced with $AB=B$ and $BA=A$ .)

Comment: Unsure why downvoted? Please explain.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a solution for any $n\times n$ matrices. If $B=BA$ and $A=AB$, then $A=ABA$. But $ABA=AA=A^2=0$, so $A=0$. Similarly for $B$.

Comment: $A^2=0$ doesn't necessarily mean $A=0$ for matrices.

Comment: I know. I guess I should've been more clear. We have $A=ABA$, and we also have $ABA=A^2$. Since $A^2=0$ by hypothesis, and since $A=A^2$ by transitivity, we get $A=0$.

Comment: OK thanks for clearing it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the version with $A B = B$ better. This means in particular that if $v \in \operatorname{im} B$ then $A v = v$. In turn this means that either $\operatorname{im} B = 0$ or *no power of $A$ can ever be zero* (including $A^2$). But your other hypotheses prohibit both of these things.

(The version with $A B = A$, etc. is converted to this version by taking the transpose.)

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice proof.